# How to hide "post" link from the admin bar

Tags: admin-bar

After studying several blogs, I figured out that to add/edit/delete admin bar items need to do something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse20131211_admin_bar' );

function wpse20131211_admin_bar() {
   global $wp_admin_bar;
   $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
   $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
}
```

But with this I can remove comments links, wp logo etc. But can't remove the **Post** link under the **+ New** menu on the admin bar.
[image: post link under admin bar]

I tried with:

```
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('post');
```

and similarly with `'posts'`, `'add-post'` etc. But failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
```

It will remove **Post** link under the admin bar's **+ New** link.

**LEARN MORE:** [**`remove_node()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) - WordPress Codex

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use following code for removing new post from admin bar using `remove_node`.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse126067_remove_newpost', 999 );

function wpse126067_remove_newpost ( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
}
```